# Weak convergence in Hilbert space L2 implies convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Does weak convergence in $L^2$ (for $X_n, X \in L^2$ we say that $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ ($X_n \rightarrow^w X$) if for every $Y\in L^2$ we have $\mathbb{E}X_nY \rightarrow \mathbb{E}XY$) implies convergence in distribution ($X_n \rightarrow^D X$ if $F_{X_n} \rightarrow F_{X}$ in every point of continuity of $F_X$)? Maybe we need some extra assumptions? If it is so, how to prove that fact?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak convergence is not enough in order to give convergence in distribution. For example, take $\Omega:=[0,1]$, and $X_n\left(\omega\right):=\sin\left(\pi n\omega\right)$. Then $X_n\to 0$ weakly but not in distribution. Indeed, if a sequence $ X_n\to 0$ in distribution, then $X_n\to 0$ in probability and since $\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert\leqslant 1$, this implies that $\mathbb E\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert\to 0$, which is not the case (or more directly, in the definition of convergence in distribution given by $\mathbb Ef(X_n)\to\mathbb E f(X)$ for any continuous and bounded $f$, choose $f\colon x\mapsto \min\left\{1,\left\lvert x\right\rvert    \right\}$.

But strong convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in probability which implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I assume that we already have $F_{X_n} \rightarrow F$ (and $F$ is CDF) and $X_n$ converges weakly to some $Z$. Would that imply that CDF of $Z$ is $F$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, in the previous version it should have been $f(0)$ instead of $0$. Four years later, I think that it is better to give an example of $f$.

Comment: It's interesting to note, though, that a weak $L^2$ convergent sequence is bounded in $L^2$, hence tight, hence admits a subsequence converging in distribution to some limit.  But that limit may not equal (in distribution) the weak $L^2$ limit.  I found it nice to consider $X_n(\omega) = e^{2 \pi n i \omega}$ in which the $L^2$ weak limit is zero, but the limit in distribution is the uniform distribution on the unit circle.